# Error when installing Hosted Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I built a chrome extension. I don't want to host it (yet) in the chrome webstore. I want to self host it. I have packaged the .crx, and deployed it to my localhost. Here is the code I use to serve it:

```
app.get('/myext.crx', function(req, res){
  var file = __dirname + '/public/myext.crx';
  res.download(file);
});
```

Then I have an anchor tag that points to the file:

```
<a href="/myext.crx">Install <strong>myExt for Chrome</strong></a>
```

When it downloads, it has the correct content-type header (per the instructions http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting.html). Here is the info from the Network tab in Chrome Devtools when I click the anchor:

```
**Response Headers**
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Description:File Transfer
Content-disposition:attachment; filename=myext.crx
Content-type:application/x-chrome-extension
Date:Sat, 14 Dec 2013 07:09:46 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Express
```

It all looks good, but Chrome still shows me the yellow banner error saying "Apps, extensions, and user scripts cannot be added from this website".

Am I missing a setting in the manifest? Can someone tell me what the issue is? Does it have anything to do with the fact that I am serving on localhost and the "homepage_url" and the "update_url" both point to my actual domain name?

Anyone, please.

**UPDATE**
It downloads the file, but gives me the aforementioned error. If I open Tools > Extensions and then drag the file from the bottom of Chrome onto the Extensions page, it won't install it. Nothing happens. HOWEVER, if I open a Finder window and drag it from the Finder window onto Tools > Extensions page, it installs fine.

Not sure if this info helps or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is starting to [block extension installs](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html) that are not from the Chrome Web Store. If you don't want an extension to be fully published in the CWS, you can limit the audience with the [publish to test accounts](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/publish#testaccounts) or accessible by URL only features.

Comment: Thanks Mr Williams. That is exactly what I was looking for. I will go that route.